# Why did my ceiling fan stop responding to the remote?

Tags: ceiling, fans

My ceiling fan stopped responding to my remote control. The fan does not shut off and continuously runs on high speed unless I cut the power.

The remote has a separate button for the light and other buttons for the speed

The light on the remote does turn on when buttons pressed.

Is this a receiver issue?

Comment: Have you changed the battery in the remote?

Comment: do the other buttons beside speed work?

Answer (score 3):

If you still have or can obtain the instructions for the remote, you could try re-pairing the remote to the fan control. Yes the light still works, but the little computers inside (everything nowadays has little computers inside) may need a hard reset.

It is also possible that the fan part of the receiver's electronics has failed "on". If so, time for a new remote & receiver.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but it has happened to me so I'll mention it. One day all my remotes in the living room stopped working at the same time. I found that someone had put a book down on top of a little-used remote, pressing one of its buttons. It was emitting a continuous IR beam with its digital encoding that completely scrambled any other attempt by another remote to communicate with its receiver.

So look for a remote in the room that is interfering with your fan remote. A phone camera can usually see an IR remote that is transmitting as a little white dot on the business end of the remote.

Comment: If IR-based, you can hold the "good" remote right up to the dark tinted IR receiver window and cup with your hand to eliminate the possibly of outside interference. Most fan remotes i've seen are RF though...